# Changes to mongo collection not visible across sessions

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

this is my mongo config:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions() {
        return new MongoCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(new OffsetDateTimeReadConverter(), new OffsetDateTimeWriteConverter()));
    }

    @Bean
    public ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener() {
        return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(validator());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

and:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/my-database
```

I have noticed that whatever changes I am making to my collection in the Spring Boot service, whether I use `repository` or `MongoOperations`, `save` or `find`, they are visible only during the lifetime of the Spring Boot service and are NOT visible with command line mongo interface. Also the documents that I add with mongo command line are NOT visible to the spring boot service.
To my knowledge I have only one instance of mongodb, only one is visible in Task manager. I double checked the name of db and collection, too.
What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the problem was caused by embedded MongoDB:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Despite the scope being `test`, the embedded server run also for the main configuration. I could observe this behaviour only in eclipse, not in Intellij.

I could solve or at least circumvent the problem by excluding the embedded configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MyApplication
```